# Solve $xy'(\cos(2x^3)\cos(x)-\sin(2x^3)\sin(x)) -y(6x^3+x)\sin(2x^3+x)+(12x^3+2x)\sin(2x^3+x)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve this differential equation. What I'm looking for is a way to simplify this equation. Can anybody give me hints/tricks to understand the following equation better:

\begin{align*}
xy'(\cos(2x^3)\cos(x)-\sin(2x^3)&\sin(x))-y(6x^3+x)\sin(2x^3+x)\\&+(12x^3+2x)\sin(2x^3+x)=0
\end{align*}

Ultimately I want to separate variables and integrate to solve for $y(x)$

Thanks for your help :)

**Edit:** Please If you can help me solve this differential equation, any help would be appreciated :)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that : $\cos(2x^3)\cos(x)−\sin(2x^3)\sin(x) = \cos(2x^3+x)$

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that two first term of the equation: $$xy'(\cos(2x^3)\cos(x)-\sin(2x^3)\sin(x)) - y(6x^3+x)\sin(2x^3+x)$$ is somehow a part of total differential of $$xy(\cos(2x^3+x))$$ Since $$d\left(x\cos(2x^3+x)y\right)=x\cos(2x^3+x)y'+y\left(\cos(2x^3+x)-(6x^3+x)\sin(2x^3+x)\right)$$

Comment: I hope you awaken refreshed and eager for a new day!

Comment: @amWhy: I become refreshed whenever you wish me that Amy. Thanks :-)